# How can I associate specific tag with specific syntax highlighting

Tags: discussion, support, syntax-highlighting

My understanding based on what I've read on meta is that syntax code highlighter applies specific syntax code highlighting if question is tagged with some corresponding tag.

The thing is that it's not always relevant to add language tag for the question but it would be appropriate to treat this language as default one for syntax highlighting. For example, gradle code is groovy, but tagging all gradle questions them as groovy questions would be a mistake.

So, is it possible to edit some tag information to sort of point out what is default highlighter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only moderators are able to change the default syntax highlighting on a per-tag basis. If you have good reasons for having a default highlighter applied to a tag, you will need to bring it up on that site's Meta as a feature-request.

Chances are it will be applied, **but** one huge thing you have to keep in mind is tags that are very often used in conjunction with other tags which have a different highlighter. For example, HTML is highlighted differently than CSS, but those tags are very often used together. When two tags are used on the same question but have *different* highlighters applied to them, *all* code in the question will revert to default and the highlighting script will attempt to determine the language on its own.

Comment: Can we see this information in tag wiki as a read-only field?

Comment: @shabunc Yes, the currently assigned language is visible at the very bottom of the tag wiki info page (below the edit and history links). It's in plain-text for non-moderators, and is completely hidden on sites which don't have default syntax highlighting enabled for tags.

Comment: Thanks! Talking specifically of gradle - would it be appropriate to edit this particular question and add "feature-request" task or the better strategy is to  create new one?

Comment: @shabunc This is the network Meta and is not meant for site-specific issues. I'm assuming you want it changed on Stack Overflow, so you'd need to post about it on [Meta Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com).